# Breaking a single page into multiple files

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Whats the standard method for dividing page content into multiple files, so that all code is not in one file. Below code snippet is contained in one file, shouldn't I refer to each div id page in a separate file, is there a standard practice for this ?

```
   <div id="page-1" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
        <h1>Page 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Page 1 content</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#page-1" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid" class="ui-btn-active">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page-2" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page-3" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="page-2" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
        <h1>Page 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Page 2 content</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#page-1" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page-2" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid" class="ui-btn-active">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page-3" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="page-3" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
        <h1>Page 3</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Page 3 content</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#page-1" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page-2" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page-3" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid" class="ui-btn-active">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Comment: I believe jQuery mobile has all of the pages inside of the index page.

Comment: You might be able to ajax a different page from somewhere else on the server with jQuery mobile.  Looking through the documentation, they don't really go into detail about it.

Comment: @SethenMaleno Here is the specific page in the jQuery Mobile documentation that refers to how remote pages are brought into the DOM via AJAX: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html

Comment: As I said before, you might be able to do it with AJAX.  I must have missed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take each `data-role="page` and `data-role="dialog"` element and paste it into a file like below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My Page's Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/custom.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/custom.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        [Your data-role="page" tag goes here]
    </body>

</html>
```

You may be thinking to yourself, `really? why duplicate so much in every file?`. The reason is that no matter where the user enters your site they will have all assets needed to load any page. This is helpful as well since jQuery Mobile uses AJAX to pull subsequent pages into the DOM and if all of your code is always available, then each page loaded will function properly.

Notice I added a `/js/custom.js` and `/css/custom.css` files after jQuery Mobile has been included. This is for all of the custom JS/CSS for your whole site.

When you link between pages, use absolute URLS:

```
<a href="/hotel/room/special.html">My Link</a>
```

This way you will always be pointing to the correct URL and if the page is already loaded in the DOM this helps ensure that the version already in the DOM is used rather than pulling-in another version (which can break your site if there are two of the same page in the DOM at once).